# Problemas al crear una lista booleana

Tags: reactjs, lista, booleano

Estoy buscando crear una lista con React que reciba un array o una matriz como props y lea por cada elemento un string y un boolean y que el boolean le indique si mostrar una imagen u otra.
La idea es tener una lista que muestre opciones disponibles y no disponibles para un plan determinado en una página de ventas.

Attribute 1 ✓

Attribute 2 ✗

Attribute 3 ✓

Attribute 4 ✗

Attribute 5 ✗

Attribute 6 ✓

A continuación les dejo lo más cerca que he podido llegar:

```
import React from 'react';

import yes from '../...'
import no from '../...'

class Cont extends React.Component
{
   render(props)
   {
      const flag = this.props.Flags;
      const listFlag = flag.map((flag)=>
         <p>{flag ? <img id='image' src={yes} alt='image'/>:<img id='image' src={no} alt='image'/>}</p>
      );

      const list = this.props.Lists;
      const listItem = list.map((list)=>
         <li>
            <p id='whoknows'>{list}</p>
            <p>{listFlag}</p>
      );
      
      return(
         <div id="flex">
            <ul>
            {listItems}
            </ul>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
export default Cont;
```

Entiendo cual es mi error, pero desconozco cual es la forma correcta de hacerlo.
Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer. Un saludo!

Comment: exactamente cual es el error que tienes?

Comment: @Isaac Cuando se le introduce por ejemplo [true, false, true, false] en una lista [l1, l2, l3, l4], al renderlizar, crea una lista l1 con un true seguido de 4 imagenes [true, false, true, false]. Debajo sigue con la lista l2 y anidado, de nuevo 4 imagenes [true, false, true, false]. Todavía no domino como introducir código en un comentario